# best practice for conditional rendering with SSR in Next.js

Tags: next.js

in my Next.js app i want to render a mobile-/ desktop-header based on the width of the device. In general this is a simple task, i did many times in normal react, using hooks like useWindowDimensions, where I check the width of the window object and use this parameter for a simple condition.
In Next.js however I ran into the problem, that my app is pre-rendert on the server, so of course there is no window object, that I could use for the condition.
Things I tried:

- dynamic import of the component, this means the component didn't get pre-rendert on the server, but only on the client. This would work, but I didn't use the benefit of SSR, and for SEO reasons I want to pre-render "key-components" like the header.
- I just picked a condition for SSR like render always the mobile-header for example and on the CSR I just render on the real condition. This would solve my issue with render always "key-components" on server side, so SEO is happy, but i run in an ugly warning about content mismatch between server and client, because when I render the app on desktop device, my first render on client side of course would be the desktop-header. So this doesn't seem to be a good solution either.
- Next I tried to render a certain condition like before, so render always the mobile-header on server AND client side and use a useEffect hook only on mount `useEffect({...}, [])`  which then check the real condition and trigger a re-render with the correct condition. This would solve my SEO-thing, and also the ugly content mismatch warning. BUT I run into a noticeable layout-shift, where the user sees the mobile-header first and after half a second the header changes to the desktop-header. ugly stuff..
- So I got my next idea, which was checking the user-agent or device type with getServersideProps and somehow use this info for a conditional rendering on server-side. This doesn't really work out to well, specially I would want to use it in my _app.tsx so I don't have to write this stuff for every page again and again. In a discussion [thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10874) in the official Next.js repo I found, that getServersideProps doesn't work in _app.js yet, only getInitialProps, which is deprecated, and shouldn't be used anymore...

So, to make things short, there has to be a good way to render components in Next.js without the above problems. I just couldn't figure out yet, what is best practice for this kind of stuff.

I would appreciate any hints, tipps or advices in this topic ❤️

Comment: Couldn't this be solved by CSS?

Comment: not if you want to pre-render only the necessary components

Comment: Its seems like the layout shift is the only way to go. `uselayouteffect` probably wouldn't work in this case based my own experience because of ssr. But you can try it out if it can solve the layout shifting issue. But you are likely to get another big warning

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using css by creating 2 components, one for mobile, one for desktop and then hiding the mobile header on desktop view, hiding the desktop header on mobile view

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I too had to render totally separate layout on desktop vs tablet / mobile. I also really wanted to take advantage of SSR.

So here's a solution that works well for me. I'm using Next 14, TS 5.2.2, and the newer app router, but this could also work with page router.

It's based on the the last approach listed above, and is the most bullet proof and "kosher" that I could find, but it does involve the downside of writing to search params.

1. Examine user agent strings in middleware:

```
// src/middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse, userAgent } from 'next/server'
import { getSelectorsByUserAgent } from 'react-device-detect'

export const middleware = async (request: NextRequest) => {

  const ua = userAgent(request)
  const { isMobileOnly, isTablet, isDesktop } = getSelectorsByUserAgent(ua.ua)
  const agent = isMobileOnly ? 'phone' : (isTablet ? 'tablet' : (isDesktop ?  'desktop' : 'unknown'))
  const { nextUrl: url } = request
  url.searchParams.set('agent', agent)
  return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
}
```

2. Examine the searchParams in a route page:

```
// src/app/[slug]/page.tsx

import React from 'react'

import { Desktop, TouchDevice } from './scroll-snap'

  // From nextjs source 
type PageProps = {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}

const Page: React.FC<PageProps> = ({ searchParams }) => {

    // see src/middleware.ts
  const agent = searchParams?.agent

  if (agent === 'desktop') {
    return <Desktop />
  }
  else if (agent === 'tablet') {
    return <TouchDevice isTablet={true} />
  }
  return <TouchDevice isTablet={false} />
}

export default Page
```